# had a not serializable result: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result

Tags: apache, hadoop

```
private static JavaPairRDD<Integer, Result> getCompanyDataRDD(JavaSparkContext sc) throws IOException {
        return sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(companyDAO.getCompnayDataConfiguration(), TableInputFormat.class, ImmutableBytesWritable.class,
            Result.class).mapToPair(new PairFunction<Tuple2<ImmutableBytesWritable, Result>, Integer, Result>() {

            public Tuple2<Integer, Result> call(Tuple2<ImmutableBytesWritable, Result> t) throws Exception {
                System.out.println("In getCompanyDataRDD"+t._2);

                String cknid = Bytes.toString(t._1.get());
                System.out.println("processing cknids is:"+cknid);
                Integer cknidInt = Integer.parseInt(cknid);
                Tuple2<Integer, Result> returnTuple = new Tuple2<Integer, Result>(cknidInt, t._2);
                return returnTuple;
            }
        });
    }
```

I am doing scan on table fetchint in mapToPair with  had a not serializable result: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result

Comment: I am getting below error

java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result

Comment: i am getting below error

Comment: provide error stack trace, and please provide a more complete description of your problem. Your current one is lacking.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the problem with Not serialization exception for Result. 
I resolved it.

Please try this.

conf.set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
    conf.registerKryoClasses(Array(classOf[org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result]))

and try to persist with MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER.

Please let me know this works for you.